# Understanding csync2 & lsyncd Syncing Mechanism

Tags: linux, replication, lsyncd

So I have two Servers configured for file replication. Imagine one being "Server1" and the other one is "Server2". I Configured lcyncd and csync2 on both nodes and sync work perfectly.

I was wondering what happens at Server2 when I add new files to Server1's syncing folder. If I create a new file in Server1, lsyncd in Server1 detect the change and trigger csync2 to sync that file to Server2. **At the same time, lsyncd in Server2 detects that new file it will also start to sync that file to Server1 ryt? or something else?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/paper.pdf, from my understanding, lsyncd pretty much runs a fs watch on the dirs, and pushes any changes, when a after it pushes to it's peers, csync uses the conflict resolution algorithms (younger or older, bigger or smaller, left or right host, etc).